# Making a Sprite move only when pressing?

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite, game-physics

I have a circle on the screen that moves right whenever I press on the right side of the screen, and left when I press on the left side of screen. Now I need to make it so when I begin a touch, my circle moves right, but if I release my touch, then the circle will stop until I press on the screen again.

This is in my touchesBegan function.

```
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {


    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    if location.x < self.size.width / 2 {

        let moveLeft = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width / 3, duration: 1.0)
        Ball.runAction(moveLeft)

    }
    else {

        let moveRight = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width / 1.445, duration: 1.0)
        Ball.runAction(moveRight)


        }





    }
```

Here is what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically something like this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if location.x < self.size.width / 2 {

            let moveLeft = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width / 3, duration: 1.0)
            Ball.runAction(moveLeft, withKey:"moveLeft")
        }
        else {
            let moveRight = SKAction.moveToX(self.frame.width / 1.445, duration: 1.0)
            Ball.runAction(moveRight withKey:"moveRight")
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    Ball.removeActionForKey("moveLeft")
    Ball.removeActionForKey("moveRight")
}
```

I suggest you'll handle the keys a bit smarter than hard-coding them as strings every time you need them, but this is the gist.